# SQL Server 2008 - Finding duplicates using ROW_NUMBER

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have the following SQL which works to find duplicates

```
SELECT  *
FROM (SELECT
      id,
      ShipAddress,
      ShipZIPPostal,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY shipaddress, shipzippostal ORDER BY shipaddress) ROWNUM
FROM orders
WHERE CONVERT(date, orderdate) = CONVERT(date, GETDATE())) x
WHERE rownum > 1
```

I would like to only see rows where, if the value of Rownum > 1 then i would like to see its corresponding row where rownum =1.

So basically, if a row has duplicates, i want to see the original row and all its duplicates.

If a row does not have duplicates, then i don't want to see it (it will have rownum = 1 )

How would i do this please?

cheers

Answer (score 6):

Use `count(*)` rather than `row_number()`:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT id, ShipAddress, ShipZIPPostal,
             COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY shipaddress, shipzippostal) as cnt
      FROM orders
      WHERE CONVERT(date, orderdate) = CONVERT(date, GETDATE())
     ) x
WHERE cnt > 1;
```

Comment: Could you please explain why this would work? thanks

Comment: @oba2311 . . . I don't understand your question.  The OP is asking for a `count()`, not a `row_number()` -- it seems pretty apparent what the difference is.  Perhaps you should ask a question if there is something you don't understand (after reviewing the functions in the documentation).

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Gordon's answer, if you want to keep the row_number() approach for some academic reason, you can do this:

```
SELECT  *
FROM (SELECT
      id,
      ShipAddress,
      ShipZIPPostal,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY shipaddress, shipzippostal ORDER BY shipaddress) ROWNUM
FROM orders
WHERE CONVERT(date, orderdate) = CONVERT(date, GETDATE())) x
WHERE EXISTS(
 SELECT * FROM x x2
 WHERE x.shipaddress=x2.shipaddress
 AND x.shipzippostal=x2.shipzippostal
 AND x2.ROWNUM>1
)
```

I'd actually prefer a cte structure like this personally:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT
      id,
      ShipAddress,
      ShipZIPPostal,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY shipaddress, shipzippostal ORDER BY shipaddress) ROWNUM
  FROM orders
  WHERE CONVERT(date, orderdate) = CONVERT(date, GETDATE())
) 
SELECT  *
FROM cte
WHERE EXISTS(
 SELECT * FROM cte x2
 WHERE cte.shipaddress=x2.shipaddress
 AND cte.shipzippostal=x2.shipzippostal
 AND x2.ROWNUM>1
)
```

Comment: Your first approach won't work, the `x` in the `where exists` is not defined. I agree a CTE is a cleaner solution (if `row_number` is necessary)

Comment: Well in the first approach, `x` is the alias of the derived table in the main query.   I haven't tested, but I would think the EXISTS() function would have access to it.   With a CTE approach, it should definitely work.

Comment: No it doesn't work, it only works in the `where` clause, where you link the where condition to the main query. You would have to re-write the `x` table definition to select from in the `exists`. This is why CTE is much better.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a second row_number, but change the order by to ID so it will be different, and compare the 2 row_numbers

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    (SELECT
        id,
        ShipAddress,
        ShipZIPPostal,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY shipaddress,shipzippostal ORDER BY id) ROWNUM1,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY shipaddress,shipzippostal ORDER BY id DESC) ROWNUM2
     FROM
        orders
     WHERE
        CONVERT(DATE,orderdate) = CONVERT(DATE,GETDATE())
    ) x
WHERE
    ROWNUM1 <> ROWNUM2
```